# How do Java and C# mimic header file construction?

Tags: java, c#, header, programming-languages

[Programming Language Pragmatics 4ed by Michael Scott](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/scottcd/3b_spcom.pdf)  says that Java and C# can mimic header files in C and C++:

> To mimic the software engineering practice of early header ﬁle construction,
>   a Java or C# design team can **create skeleton versions of (the public classes of)
>   its packages or namespaces**, which can then be **used, concurrently and independently, by the programmers responsible for the full versions**.

What does  it mean by:

- "create skeleton versions of (the public classes of)
  its packages or namespaces"
- "used, concurrently and independently, by the programmers responsible for the full versions"?

Thanks.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. What is a skeleton? Bones without any meat, meaning just a definition of what the final fleshed out version will be at the end. You can use that skeleton in place of the final construct during development, even though the meat of it isn't present.

Comment: This book seems to be rather less helpful than would be desired. In practice, this would be done by defining Java interfaces (and some data objects), and then using mocks to work on clients.

Answer (score 0):

> "create skeleton versions of (the public classes of) its packages or namespaces"

That means that the designers write Java or C# source code with some or all of the implementation details missing; e.g. interfaces

> "used, concurrently and independently, by the programmers responsible for the full versions"?

That means that the programmers write the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It means creating versions of the classes that have no implementation. In C#, the usual approach is to make all members throw `NotImplementedException`. E.g.:

```
public class Database
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

A similar approach would be create just interfaces, but not the classes that implement them, e.g.:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees();
}
```

Though this approach limits your design in some ways, e.g. you can't use it for types with public static members.

With both approaches, other programmers can start writing code that uses `Database`/`IDatabase`, even though the implementation is not done yet. One issue with this practice is that those programmers can't test their code, unless they create their own test implementation (e.g. using mocking).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "you can't use it for types with public static members"? I am interested in know more about the limitations and advantages between the two approaches.

Comment: Interfaces can't have static members. So, you can't use an interface to act as the skeleton for a class with public static members, you would need to use actual class with no implementation.